# nodejs and heroku: throw new Error('"name" and "value" are required for setHeader().');

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Can you please help, I get the Application Error on heroku, although locally app works fine.

Seems this is the problem in _http_outgoing.js:333:

```
throw new Error('"name" and "value" are required for setHeader().');
```

More specifically:

```
2015-04-07T05:22:23.244579+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845835+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Error('"name" and "value" are required for setHeader().');
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845840+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:333:11)
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845845+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/simplecrawler/lib/crawler.js:768:11
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845847+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845848+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845837+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-04-07T05:22:23.845838+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
```

And my app.js

```
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)
console.log("http server listening on %d", port)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: hello, are you setting any custom headers? can you post the snippet of your code

Comment: not that i know of. I added a part from my app.js

Answer (score 0):

From what the error is saying, and based off your title, you appear to be just running the setHeader function without arguments, when this is a value setter function, and requires two arguments: The first (name) is the name of the header whose value you would like to set, and the second (value) is the value you would like to set the header to. Hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the simplecrawler module. Implemented a new version, where this problem is fixed, and it worked.

Comment: This is not acceptable. You should provide the version you switched to as others who may be having a similar issue will find this and have to continue to dig.